# State lat/long from CSV-file

Tags: qgis, csv, wgs84

I am trying to place points in QGIS that are given in a csv-file, coordinates are given in WGS84 (4326) but the positions are like this

```
LAT;LONG
5724.3180;1548.4021
```

I can't get QGIS to place them correctly. When I divide them by 100 I get the extent correct but the place is not correct `57.24318 / 15.4021`

It should be Hultsfred. The points represent trees along Väg 23 between Målilla-Hultsfred

How do I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: can you explain more what is not correct about the place you get? and why you believe the coordinates are in 100xwgs84 (which is a very weird idea)

Comment: The coordinates are somewhere East of Värnamo, Sweden, if this "divide by 100" hypothesis is correct.

Comment: Thanks but it should be Hultsfred

Comment: And how do you know this? What exactly should these points represent?

Comment: I dont know how to attach a file

Comment: The points represent trees along Väg 23 between Målilla-Hultsfred

Comment: @ÅkeEriksson please have a look at the second option in my answer. Since we're talking about trees, an accuracy down to half a m would be necessary, I guess. If you could talk to whoever gave you that data, it would be helpful I think.

Comment: We gather the data ourself, this is just a test to try simplifying our work. Sometimes the drawings are changed very late in the project and we have to measure some trees again and I was thinking that I could reduce that work. And I am somewhat new to Qgis after using ArcView 3.2 since 97. So I am learning, thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the DMS-notations at the correct places, `5724.3180;1548.4021` becomes `57°24'31.8" N; 15°48'40.21" E` - which is placed exactly where it should be as you state in the comments.

I suggest you load the data into QGIS as a table without geometry. Then you use the field calculator with the following expressions to create new latitude and longitude fields:

`substr(LAT,1,2)||'°'||substr(LAT,3,2)||'\''||substr(LAT,6,2)||'.'||substr(LAT,8)||'"N'`
`substr(LONG,1,2)||'°'||substr(LONG,3,2)||'\''||substr(LONG,6,2)||'.'||substr(LONG,8)||'"E'`

Then save to `.csv`, then reload with the new coordinates as DMS.

You could also use excel for this editing, I guess.

---

It is also likely, as @mkennedy pointed out, that the original coordinates were `DDMM.mmmm`. In this case the expression would be:

`substr(LAT,1,2)||'°'||substr(LAT,3)||'\'N'`

And similarly for the East-coordinate.

Comment: Thanks /Tack så mycket

Comment: You're welcome @ÅkeEriksson. I just changed the expression, because I initially forgot about the point in the coordinates.

Comment: @Erik I would have guessed the values were DDMM.mmmm. Good catch!

Comment: @mkennedy which seems even more fitting, since it explains the point. The difference to the DMS is small enough.